# Destroy tkinter window from secondary process

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, user-input

I have a program that, at one point, pops up a tkinter window. Once you close the window, the program continues. This is ok, but I need the program to close the window after 2 minutes if the user hasn't done so.

Since I use Pyinstaller, I understand that I need to use multiprocess instead of threading. Either way, when I call root.destroy() from a process, it fails because it can't find it ("name 'root' is not defined"; command line says this, IDLE says nothing).

I've spent hours researching how to implement this ""simple"" feature. I just want a quick fix. This wasn't even my original issue, originally the secondary process would bypass or "enter a value" into an "input()" in the main process so that it would continue, but I don't know how to do that either. If that's easier to solve, I'm up for it.

I've tried many things but I guess I'll just paste where I'm at:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import tkinter as tk

def func2():
    global root
    time.sleep(3)
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    T = tk.Text(root, height=20, width=60)
    T.pack()
    T.insert(tk.END, "test")

    p2 = Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()

    tk.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Hello. You can use tkinter `after` mechanism to register something todo after a while. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method

Comment: THANK you!!
Please change the comment into an answer so that I can select it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/7414759)

Comment: @Elektrofire: Done I created an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tkinter `after` mechanism to register something todo after a while. See:
[tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method)